# Why come to the conclusion that a Borel set is measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

I am reading this proof of measurability of Borel sets. It eventually reaches the conclusion

> Since $C$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing the open intervals, the Borel sets are a subset of $C$.

I do not understand from where they obtained this conclusion. Why are all Borel sets in $C$?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So $C$ is a $\sigma$-algebra that contains the open intervals. The **smallest** $\sigma$-algebra that contains all open intervals is, by definition, the Borel family of sets. Therefore, any Borel set must belong to $C$.

The important thing to remember is that, when you have a collection of sets $X$, the $\sigma$-algebra generated by that collection, $\sigma(X)$, is the **smallest** (the one with the "fewest" sets) $\sigma$-algebra that includes that collection. If 1) all sets satisfying a certaing property $P$ constitute a $\sigma$-algebra, and 2) the sets of $X$ satisfy $P$, then you can conclude that such $\sigma$-algebra has to be at least $\sigma(X)$ (must include it). This is the main point, a technique somtimes called *the technique of convenient sets*.